# No scoped body style in Svelte

Tags: css, svelte

How do I style the body To achieve different styling for the "body" element on individual pages in Svelte, how can I avoid the":global(body)" in the style tags, which applies the same style to all pages?

I tried  but still the :global(body) tag styled all pages.

Comment: What are you using for navigation between pages? Are the components for the previous page unmounted correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using **[sveltekit](https://kit.svelte.dev/)** ; here's what you could do.

Create and import different styles for different routes into `+page.svelte` (implements CSS on it's content only) instead of the `+layout.svelte` (implements CSS on everything in `slot`).
The image below shows the **about** "page" (`route`) with `+page.svelte` and `about.css`,

[image: files]

Inside `+page.svelte` of **about** "page", Import `about.css` like;

```
import "./about.css"
```

You can do this for all your different pages.
Hope it helps.